# Unexpected behaviour when using ORDER BY - Days of the week being printed out in an incorrect order

Tags: sql

I am trying to print out three different columns; the employee's last name, their hire date, and the actual day that they were hired on, so either Monday, Tuesday etc. I am required to order the 'day' column - the column that represents what day they were hired on - by the days of the week

> i.e : Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday.

However, when the table has been printed out, the employee that was hired on Monday, for example, is being printed out in the wrong place. They are appearing after the employees that were hired on Tuesday, when really they should be appearing before them.
 Is there a subtle reason why this is happening? I have tried using `CAST`but either I am using it wrong or it is not applicable to this situation.

As you can see below, every other employee is being printed out in the correct order, based on the days they were hired.

MySQL:

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date, date_format(hire_date, "%a") as day 
FROM employees 
ORDER BY field(day, 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
```

Output:

```
+-----------+------------+------+
| last_name | hire_date  | day  |
+-----------+------------+------+
| Ernst     | 1991-05-21 | Tue  |
| Mourgos   | 1999-11-16 | Tue  |
| Rajs      | 1995-10-17 | Tue  |
| Taylor    | 1998-03-24 | Tue  |
| Higgins   | 1994-06-07 | Tue  |
| Gietz     | 1994-06-07 | Tue  |
| Grant     | 1999-05-24 | Mon  |
| King      | 1987-06-17 | Wed  |
| Da Haan   | 1993-01-13 | Wed  |
| Hunold    | 1990-01-03 | Wed  |
| Davies    | 1997-01-29 | Wed  |
| Kochhar   | 1989-09-21 | Thu  |
| Vargas    | 1998-07-09 | Thu  |
| Whalen    | 1987-09-17 | Thu  |
| ZLotkey   | 2000-01-29 | Sat  |
| Abel      | 1996-05-11 | Sat  |
| Harstein  | 1996-02-17 | Sat  |
| Lorentz   | 1999-02-07 | Sun  |
| Matos     | 1998-03-15 | Sun  |
| Fay       | 1997-08-17 | Sun  |
+-----------+------------+------+
```

Comment: `'Tues'`? There is no such value in the `day` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`field()` returns `0` for not found values. You specified `Tues` as value, but your data is `Tue`. Therefore in the result `Tue` is listed before `Mon`.

You will get correct order with

```
order by field(day, 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')
```

[Manual entry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

> Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list. **Returns 0 if str is not found.**

But even simpler solution would be

```
ORDER BY WEEKDAY(hire_date)
```

- read more about `WEEKDAY()` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday)

> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Didn't notice I made that mistake at all.